# Compiler Emitting Message from mutable and immutable reference

Tags: rust

I am reading a book of the "The Rust Programming Language". Here are two example codes extracted from the book.

```
fn first_word(s: &String) -> usize {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();

    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return i;
        }
    }

    s.len()
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello world");

    let word = first_word(&s); 

    s.clear(); // this empties the String, making it equal to ""

    // println!("the first word is: {}", word);
}

fn first_word(s: &String) -> &str {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();

    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return &s[0..i];
        }
    }

    &s[..]
}
```

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling ownership v0.1.0 (file:///projects/ownership)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:18:5
   |
16 |     let word = first_word(&s);
   |                           -- immutable borrow occurs here
17 | 
18 |     s.clear(); // error!
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
19 | 
20 |     println!("the first word is: {}", word);
   |                                       ---- immutable borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `ownership` due to previous error
```

I know why the error exists and this happens when we use the second first_word function and then in the main function we clear the string and then use the result returned from the slice stored in word in the println macro. By then the slice does not exist anymore.

However, the error message emitted by the compiler is so confusing. I know we cannot have mutable and immutable of the same reference at the same time but we can have as many immutable references as we can. But I am just wondering why it says "cannot borrow `s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable". Because we only have one immutable reference s within the main function. I know the clear function take a mut reference of self (&self). If that is the case, then it makes sense but then how come if we use the first first_word function, and then it compiles and nothing happens? I just don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a typo, because `clear()` does not take a `&self` but a `&mut self`, because it mutates the value it operates upon.

In the second version it is as if you wrote:

```
fn first_word<'a>(s: &'a String) -> &'a str { /*...*/ }

//...
let word: &str = first_word(&s);
```

In the declaration of word you cannot specify the lifetime of the reference, that in `&'_ str`, it is deduced automatically, by using the declaration of `fist_word` to be the same as the lifetime of the argument, that is the borrow of `&s`.

This means that `s` is borrowed for as long as `word` exists. That is, if you add a `println!("{}", word)` ad the end of `main` then `s` is borrowed so long, and the call to `s.clear()` fails, as `String::clear(&mut self)` requires a mutable borrow that cannot exist here.

If you remove the `println!("{}", word)`, then the first borrow can be shortened and the program compiles again.

What about your first example? Well, there the function is as:

```
fn first_word<'a>(s: &'a String) -> usize { /*...*/ }
```

Note that the returned value does not have a lifetime, so it does not return a borrow. That is when you write:

```
let word = first_word(&s);
```

`s` is borrowed to call the function and when it returns it is unborrowed. Since there is no such living borrow you can call `s.clear()` without issue. Yes, now the `word` variable does not contain the actual length of `s`, and that may be wrong for you, but that is of no concern to the compiler because that does create *unsafety* (in the rusty sense of the word).

Comment: Thanks. I think I kinda understand the reason why. But could you elaborate on it a little bit more?